# CakePHP 3.7 - Access view variable from controller

Tags: variables, cakephp, view, cakephp-3.0

Inside `AppController->beforeRender()` I would to check whether a view variable is already set and see its value.

How can you access view variables from a controller in CakePHP 3.7?

This used to be possible with `$this->viewVars['variable_name']`, but it has been deprecated.

I tried `$this->viewBuilder()->getVars()` but that returns an empty array, while there certainly are view variables.

Comment: The view builder only receives the variables when the view is being built, until then they only exist in the `$viewVars` property. Why exactly do you need to access view variables from a controller? Maybe there's a better solution for whatever problem you are trying to solve by that.

Comment: Basically, I want view variables to fall back to defaults when they haven't been set. E.g. manage a 'status' variable based on whether or not a 'errors' variable is present.

Comment: If this is something that you need in lots of views, maybe an element that encapsulates that logic is the way to go?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I better implement something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarising an answer from the comments: this is not directly possible.
Accessing the variables through the `viewBuilder()` won't work because it only receives the viewvars as the view is being built.

A custom element encapsulating the variables to be accessed could be a solution.

I ended by setting some variables as default: in `AppController->initialize()` the view variable `status` is set as `"OK"`, other controllers and methods can then simply override it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cakephp 4 (I believe it works with C3 as well)

```
$this->viewVars()['variable_name']
```

Would do the trick!

Comment: I'm confirming this works in C5. I was trying to access a variable I set in the AppController beforefilter from another controller. The following code worked: `$this->viewBuilder()->getVars()['page']['id']`